# Installing libcurl 7.19+ on CentOS5

Tags: centos5

I have a CentOS 5 server that I need to install pycurl 7.19.0 on. pycurl 7.19.0 requires libcurl 7.19.x or higher. The bundled version of libcurl is 7.15.5. I can't seem to find any rpms and I'm a little hesitant to install from source.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone who may be interested here is what I did.

1. Build your desired version of
   curl/libcurl in an alternate
   directory (I used /opt/curl)
   following the instructions here http://markus.revti.com/2009/12/install-rtorrent-using-curl-in-different-path-on-centos-linux/
2. Grab the pycurl source for the appropriate libcurl version here http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
3. Run setup.py and tell it to build against your alternate libcurl, i.e.

`python setup.py install --curl-config=/opt/curl/bin/curl-config`

Breath a sigh of relief.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a new version binary RPM available for CentOS5 anywhere so you'll probably have to recompile. I'd start with http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/source/SRPMS/curl-7.21.3-3.fc15.src.rpm (and you may as well use http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/source/SRPMS/python-pycurl-7.19.0-9.fc15.src.rpm as well).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I've added my solution below.